# insert english words in single div using php

Tags: php, preg-match, non-english

i have some text that can have some English words or not.
like as:

```
منث تاب English test words سنی
من یایب
```

i want detect English words and insert all of them in single div class
so i want my function return

```
منث تاب <div class="en">English test words</div> سنی
```

i create this function:

```
    function check_english($text){
        $text_ex = array_filter(explode(" ", $text));
        $counter = 0;
        $final_text = '';
        if(strlen($text) != mb_strlen($text, 'utf-8')) return $text;
        else {
            foreach($text_ex as $word){
                $counter++;
                if($counter>1) $final_text .= " ";
                if(preg_match("/[a-z]/i",$word)) $final_text .= "<span class='en'>$word</span>";
                else $final_text .= $word;
            }
            return $final_text;
        }
    }
```

but this function return all English string in separated div class.

Answer (score 0):

This updated RegEx should capture the whole string instead of a single word.

```
/[\w\s].[\w\s]+/ig
```